# Finder Search Criteria not applied to "This Mac"

Tags: finder, spotlight, search

When applying search criteria to "This Mac" the results do not seem to match the parameters. But when I click on "Recent" then it does. I am running Catalina with the latest update. I've also reset the spotlight index though I dont think this has anything to do with it. Any ideas?

Here is an example of a search on "This Mac",

[image: Searching "This Mac"]

and the same search under "Recent"

[image: Searching "Recent"]

**UPDATE:**
After the suggestion by Alex, I found that entering the conditions in the search box works for `ThisMac` as well. Strange. The search became `text kind:mp3` or `text kind:audio` to be exact. Not sure how I would search for m4a files but that another question.

[image: Searching "ThisMac" with conditions]

Comment: By the looks of it you're searching for "1053" (just assuming because you've not pixeled it) and this is the string you're searching for in the file name. If you haven't specified that you want to search for "1053" in the file name, then the search algorithm will also search within the files' content. – What surprises me though is that in your "This Mac" search scope you get text files, header files (.h), archives and Outlook files, when you specify that you're searching for MP3s. Do you get different results if you search for, say "1053" or ".mp3" as part of the file name?

Comment: @AlexIxeras Yes the "This Mac" search should be limited to mp3 files like with Recent search but it isn't. Its like the criteria are being ignored. So I entered `1053 mp3` and it suggested in a drop down `Kind:MP3 Audio`. I accepted the suggestion and it is filtered correctly. Weird. It accepts conditions in the search box but ignores them in the search criteria. Very weird bug.